# Angular-translate con módulos externos cargados con oclazyload

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con oclazyload para la carga por la demanda de módulos externos y tengo que traducir el contenido, por lo que estoy usando `angular-translate` pero la traducción no funciona porque el código que añade la parte está dentro del controlador que se carga de forma asincrónica.

```
angular
    .module('main')
    .controller('invoicesCtrl', invoicesCtrl);

function invoicesCtrl($scope, $translatePartialLoader, $translate) {

    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('invoices');
    $translate.refresh();
    ...

}
```

La aplicación principal carga las traducciones aquí:

```
(function () {

    angular.module('main', [
        'ui.router',                // Angular flexible routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',
        'ngResource',
        'pascalprecht.translate'    // Angular-translate
    ]);

    angular.module('main').config(function ($translateProvider,     $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

        $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: './i18n/{part}/{lang}.json'
        });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
        $translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true);
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('secure');

        // Enable escaping of HTML          
        $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape');

    });

})();
```

Y para la carga asíncrona de `invoicesCtrl` y los otros controladores que uso (esta parte está funcionando bien):

```
function configState($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {
    function resolveUrl(path){
       var loadUrl = { // Any property in resolve should return a promise and is executed before the view is loaded
           loadModule: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
               // you can lazy load files for an existing module
               return $ocLazyLoad.load(path);
           }]
       };
       return loadUrl;
   }
}
```

Necesito cargar este `addPart` antes de que el propio controlador.

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('invoices');
$translate.refresh();
```

Tal vez una aproximación puede ser el uso de un evento, pero soy nuevo en javascript y no sé cómo ponerlo en práctica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné usando en el controlador de la aplicación principal una nueva función que se llama cuando el enlace de la navegación recibe un clic:

```
<li ng-class="active" ng-click="getModuleLang('invoices')">
```

Mi archivo `main.js`:

```
angular
    .module('main')
    .controller('appCtrl', appCtrl);

function appCtrl($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoader) {

    // Secure translate module added to language lazy load
    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('secure');
    $translate.refresh();

    // Function that changes the language based on the headers language buttons
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
        $translate.use(langKey);
    };

    // Load the language modula based on the navigation element clicked
    $scope.getModuleLang = function(module){
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart(module);
        $translate.refresh();       
    }
};
```